# creating a dynamic where clause in oracle apex form

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, dynamic-sql

I am creating a parameterized apex form where I take column name and its value from user via a select list.
When I use it in where clause like

```
select columnnames 
from table 
where :P592_column = :P592_value ;
```

It is not returning any output, but when I hardcode column name in place of :P592_column it is showing output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a bind variable as a dynamic column name. Instead, whitelist the columns in a `CASE` statement:

```sql
SELECT columnnames 
FROM   table 
WHERE  CASE UPPER( :P592_column )
       WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN column1
       WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN column2
       WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN column3
       WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN column4
       END = :P592_value;
```

---

Or for multiple columns:

```sql
SELECT columnnames 
FROM   table 
WHERE  CASE UPPER( :P592_column )
       WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN column1
       WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN column2
       WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN column3
       WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN column4
       END LIKE '%' || :P592_value || '%'
AND    CASE UPPER( :P592_column1 )
       WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN column1
       WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN column2
       WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN column3
       WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN column4
       END LIKE '%' || :P592_value1 || '%'
AND    CASE UPPER( :P592_column2 )
       WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN column1
       WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN column2
       WHEN 'COLUMN3' THEN column3
       WHEN 'COLUMN4' THEN column4
       END LIKE '%' || :P592_value2 || '%';
```

Comment: This probably won't scale well, though. Alternatively, you can construct your SQL statement as a string, and return that as your region source.

Comment: thank you guys, let me try these solutions. I have multiple columns like this. I think it will be better to construct sql as said by scott via sql procedure

Comment: @Scott Just make sure you do not introduce SQL injection attacks into your code if you are trying to build the query as a string by using things like [`DBMS_ASSERT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#ARPLS65376) in your procedure and you may still need to whitelist/blacklist column name if there are columns of the table you do not want to be able to filter on. The code above does not have any SQL injection issues as the bind variable values are treated as literals and the columns are hard coded.

Comment: @MTO : i have many columns. multiple columns like :P592_COLUMN,:P592_COLUMN1,:P592_COLUMN2,:P592_COLUMN3. And i have to use all these columns in where clause. Could you please suggest how I can do that, i tried to do via sql procedure but its giving me error.  To be precise, the where clause will be like :P592_COLUMN like '%:P592_VALUE%' and :P592_COLUMN1 like '%:P592_VALUE1% and :P592_COLUMN2 like '%:P592_VALUE2% and so on.

Comment: If you're building SQL using PL/SQL properly (using bind variables), SQL injection should be as much an issue as writing your SQL normally.

Comment: Thank you so much @MTO, it worked. Appreciate your help :)